# Angular 4: how can I bind dynamically input attribute of subcomponent

Tags: angular, data-binding, angular2-template

How can I set dynamically the input attribute of my subcomponent with one way binding in angular 4?

For example I have following subcomponent:

```
@Component({
    selector: 'app-page-header',
    templateUrl: './page-header.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./page-header.component.scss']
})
export class PageHeaderComponent {
    @Input() heading: string;
}
```

If I am using this subcomponent in my component as follows it works:

```
<app-page-header [heading]="'Hello world'"></app-page-header>
```

But I want dynamically set the heading attribute of my subcomponent like this

```
<app-page-header [heading]="{{myfield}}"></app-page-header>
```

or even with pipes

```
<app-page-header [heading]="{{ 'MY_TEXT_FIELD' | translate:lang }}"></app-page-header>
```

But it does not work.

How can I achieve this and how is the syntax? Thank you in advance for your answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just remove the `{{}}`.

So it should be:

`<app-page-header [heading]="myfield"></app-page-header>`

and

`<app-page-header [heading]="'MY_TEXT_FIELD' | translate:lang"></app-page-header>`

You can look that up in the 'Template syntax' section of the [Angular.io Cheatsheet](https://angular.io/guide/cheatsheet).

Comment: Glad I could help!